# Cordova Android won't build

Tags: android, cordova, ember.js

I get this error when I dive into debugging

> Successfully started process 'command '/Users/sean/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt''
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/factsumo/ember-cordova/cordova/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/armv7/debug/www/plugins/com.kernix.progresshud/www/progresshud-22be32d8c1aa4020b952c0783e7d5175-22be32d8c1aa4020b952c0783e7d5175-22be32d8c1aa4020b952c0783e7d5175-22be32d8c1aa4020b952c0783e7d5175.js: error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.

The command I'm running to get this is `./gradlew assembleDebug --info`

This is on iOS 10, using ember-cordova. Corova 6.3.0

When I do a normal build I get this error

> Execution failed for task ':processArmv7DebugResources'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/sean/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I'm using Crosswalk, but I've tried without this, and I get the same thing. Not sure what to do to get around this. I have another cordova project that doesn't have this problem, but the only difference is this project has a lot more plugins. I also tried removing the plugin it mentions, but then it just says the next plugin has the same issue.